# Add class to body on touch start rather than .scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, scroll

I have some JavaScript I'm using to add a class to my `<body>` element when the user is scrolling:

```
var $body = $('body');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $body.addClass('scrolling');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 1) {
        $body.removeClass('scrolling');
    }
});
```

This works well on desktop browsers, but on iOS (and possibly other mobile devices) the class is only added upon touch *release* rather than when the user first touches the screen to scroll.

How do I adjust this script to trigger this class upon touch, whilst still working as normal for standard desktop users?

Here's a Fiddle showing this script in action: http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/AKCCH/

Comment: CSS for what? When you scroll, a class is attached to the `<body>` element, nothing else.

Comment: The class does *do* something in my code, but that's irrelevant to this question. The question, is how do I adjust this script to work on touch rather than on scroll. That is all :)

Comment: My issue was it is not easy to see a change of class on an iPad unless I load the test into a debugger. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ontouchstart, ontouchmove and ontouchend to handle touch events.

```
var $body = $('body');

if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)
{
  $(window).bind('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $body.addClass('scrollingTouch');
  });

  $(window).bind('touchend',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 1) {
        $body.removeClass('scrollingTouch');
    }
  });
}
else
{
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      $body.addClass('scrolling');
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll <= 1) {
          $body.removeClass('scrolling');
      }
  });
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLrtr/

There might be some complications so I suggest you read [this](http://www.devinrolsen.com/basic-jquery-touchmove-event-setup/) to understand them.
Also, you might want to check these [3rd party libraries](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries) for touch events handling.

Comment: So this turns blue on touch but not visible scrolling on my iPhone with ios6 http://jsfiddle.net/BLrtr/show/

Comment: The scrolling on touch adds a separate class `scrollingTouch`, which is different from the `scrolling` class attached on scroll.

Comment: This is great, except as @mplungjan says the script seems to prevent actual touch scrolling of the page. The class is correctly added upon touch, but the page is un-scrollable.